# Module not found but it is there when pushing to Heroku

Tags: git, reactjs, github, heroku

I am trying push my project to heroku but I keep getting the error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../views/Newsfeed/Newfeed' in '/tmp/build_8a36e641e1384d378001a98e49df0ea1/client/src/routes'

The other views don't have any problem except this one? And even when I run my server locally I never get this error. What am I missing?

> $git add .
>
> $git commit -am "May the force be with you"
>
> $git push heroku master

**/src/routes/Dashboard.jsx**

**This is the only file that uses this view**

```
  import Dashboard from "views/Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";
-->    import NewsFeed from "views/NewsFeed/NewsFeed";
    import Calendar from "views/Calendar/Calendar.jsx";
    //import Widgets from "views/Widgets/Widgets.jsx";
    import UserProfile from "views/Pages/UserProfile.jsx";
    
    // @material-ui/icons
    import DashboardIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Dashboard";
    import User from "@material-ui/icons/Person";
    import DateRange from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange";
    import FeedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RssFeed";
    
    var dashRoutes = [
      {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "Dashboard",
        icon: DashboardIcon,
        component: Dashboard
      },
      {
        path: "/user-page",
        name: "User Profile",
        icon: User,
        component: UserProfile
      },
      {
        path: "/newsfeed",
        name: "Newsfeed",
        icon: FeedIcon,
  -->      component: NewsFeed
      },
      { path: "/calendar", name: "Calendar", icon: DateRange, component: Calendar },
      {
        redirect: true,
        path: "/",
        pathTo: "/dashboard",
        name: "Dashboard"
      }
    ];
    export default dashRoutes;
```

[image]

**Update**
tried changing extension to `.jsx` still error

Comment: Side note: I hope this isn't your real commit message: `git commit -am "May the force be with you"`. Those messages are important. They should accurately and concisely describe the change that you're making. See https://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html for one common set of commit message guidelines.

Comment: I did that for you guys...Your standards must be low for people on here haha!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me recently on Heroku after I did some folder restructuring.

I had one file that wouldn't resolve in the heroku build but worked fine locally.

After trying to force heroku to clear the git repo and pushing it again to heroko that didn't work.

What I ended up doing was moving that file out of my `src` and commented out imports of it and usage of that component. Then pushed a commit without that file to  heroku and the build worked.

Then I created a new file with same name as original, pasted original file code into it and uncommented the imports and usage. When I pushed that commit it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I moved my Newsfeed files into Dashboard and it pushed with no errors. I guess this is just a weird bug